# Is AppFabric 1.1 compatible with CNG Data Encryption Providers in IIS 10?

Tags: iis, appfabric, windows-server-2019

We are migrating IIS web services from a Win2016 on-prem server to a Win2019 server in the Cloud.

I need AppFabric 1.1 for WCF services so I installed it on the Win2019 server. **Problem**: every time the *AppFabric Workflow Management* service is started, one of my service account get locked in the Active Directory.

The apparent reason:

- This service account is used as *Physical Path Credentials* in the web service website *Advanced settings*.
- When started, the *AppFabric Workflow Management* service open all web.config to search for WCF configuration (I think).
- It uses the *Physical Path Credentials* identity to do so if one is defined.
- In my case, the password is encrypted using the CNG Data Encryption Providers, which is new to IIS10.
- It seems that AppFabric decipher the password with the wrong provider, get the wrong password and lock the account after a couple of retries.

Hence my question: is AppFabric 1.1 compatible with CNG Data Encryption Providers in IIS 10?

Any hint will be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: According to my search, there is no documentation or the project talk about this. I am not familiar with the AppFabric. I suggest you try it. If you have any questions, please feel free to discuss it. or If you like, you might also open a support case via [http://support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com) to contact Microsoft support team.

Answer (score 0):

AppFabric 1.1 is NOT compatible with CNG Data Encryption Providers in IIS 10.

We had to re-enter the passwords of the service accounts we use in IIS. Problem: we lost many of them.

What saved us: we can list all the passwords defined in ApplicationHost.config *** IN CLEAR *** with this command:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppool /config /xml
```

Hope this help.